# CrudRepository.deleteAll() causes InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException during testing

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm testing a Spring Boot CrudRepository interface.  The find methods work fine.  However if I try to delete something, I get an exception.

For example I have the following:

```
@Test
public void testDelete()
{
    generateTestData.saveCustomersWithoutOrders();
    customerRepository.deleteAll();
}
```

This results in this stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select orders0_.customer_id as customer3_0_0_, orders0_.id as id1_1_0_, orders0_.id as id1_1_1_, orders0_.amount as amount2_1_1_, orders0_.customer_id as customer3_1_1_ from order orders0_ where orders0_.customer_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:231)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.fireflysemantics.spring.domain.repository.CustomerRepositoryTest.testDelete(CustomerRepositoryTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementsIterator(CollectionType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementsIterator(CollectionType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions.getAllElementsIterator(CascadingActions.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions.access$100(CascadingActions.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.getCascadableChildrenIterator(CascadingActions.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeBeforeDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.remove(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.deleteAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ORDERS0_.CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER3_0_0_, ORDERS0_.ID AS ID1_1_0_, ORDERS0_.ID AS ID1_1_1_, ORDERS0_.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT2_1_1_, ORDERS0_.CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER3_1_1_ FROM ORDER[*] ORDERS0_ WHERE ORDERS0_.CUSTOMER_ID=? "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select orders0_.customer_id as customer3_0_0_, orders0_.id as id1_1_0_, orders0_.id as id1_1_1_, orders0_.amount as amount2_1_1_, orders0_.customer_id as customer3_1_1_ from order orders0_ where orders0_.customer_id=? [42001-183]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:3043)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1192)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1866)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1975)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1860)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1681)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1669)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:433)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:305)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:277)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:242)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:446)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:388)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1189)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:72)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 91 more
```

Any ideas?

TIA,
- Ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an entity named `Order` for storing customer orders.  Since `order` is a reserved word, it created problems.  Adding @Table(name="orders") solved the problem.